# Custom error view MVC with constructor exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, constructor, filter

I'm using the standard set-up with an `Error` view and `HandleErrorAttribute` registered in  `global.asax`.

This works fine when an exception is raised from `Action`, but I don't get a redirect to the error page if an exception is raised in the controller constructor. I don't know why. Is there a separate pattern for handling constructor errors?

Comment: Deleted my answer, 4 years back. Wow a non-sense... :)